# How to select an specific event by user?

Tags: sql

I got a chain of events per user and need to select an specific event but need to select those who's maximun event is that in specific. Let me explain with a table.

| User | Event |
| --- | --- |
| XYZ | Event 1 |
| XYZ | Event 2 |
| XYZ | Event 3 |
| XYZ | Event 4 |

I need to select those who are in the event 3 and haven't pass to the event 4. It is a process in the database so I need those who are stuck in the event 3.

I was trying the fuction rank () but didn't work out.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? sql-server, mysql, ect?

Comment: prestodb in athena aws

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT User, Event, 
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Event ASC) as dr
             FROM test)
SELECT User, Event FROM cte 
  WHERE User NOT IN (SELECT User FROM cte WHERE dr >= 4)
ORDER BY User DESC
```

**Result (using my provided sample data):**

```
| User | Event    |
|------|----------|
| ABC  | Event 1  |
| ABC  | Event 2  |
| ABC  | Event 3  |
```

If you only want to return the `User`, add a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT User, Event, 
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Event ASC) as dr
             FROM test)
SELECT User FROM cte 
  WHERE User NOT IN (SELECT User FROM cte WHERE dr >= 4)
GROUP BY User
ORDER BY User DESC
```

**Result:**

```
| User  |
|-------|
| ABC   |
```

**Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/E3-u7XOW).**

**Note:** If you're using *SQL Server*, you will have to wrap the keyword `User` in brackets `[User]` [like so](https://dbfiddle.uk/TqNHCj7h).

Answer (score 1):

You can try a query like:

```
SELECT user
FROM table
WHERE event = 'Event 3'
  AND user NOT IN
    (SELECT user
     FROM table
     WHERE event = 'Event 4');
```

Comment: This answer works for the provided sample data above, however, just an FYI that this solution will not work if `Event 4` is not in the table, but other events above `4` are (i.e. `Event 5`, `Event 6`, etc.) if the data gets out of sync. See the last query in my fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z-04WBH8).